# Visual Studio 2013 C++ intellisense for single cpp file?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I am using Visual Studio for a basic GUI/syntax highlighting and opened/dragged a single .cpp file in to the GUI. Whilst syntax like `return`, `new`, `int`, `double` etc is highlighting, there is no intellisense (not even for namespace std).

Is there any way the intellisense for namespace std can be activated?

Comment: Create new empty project and add your file, that seems only way.

Answer (score 1):

this is a feature that's been added to **Visual Studio 2015**, more information here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/04/29/single-file-intellisense-and-other-ide-improvements-in-vs2015.aspx

Comment: You can download the Visual Studio RC now to use it .
Also there is a channel 9 video for it :
http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/C9-GoingNative/GoingNative-37-Single-File-IntelliSense